# Using SDN for testing purposes

Tags: networking, sdn, mininet, switching, spanning-tree

I need to сheck for compliance a physical switch which uses RSTP. And instead of building a real topology I've decided to use SDN (mininet) and include my real device to SDN topology. By 'testing' I mean Conformance Test, Root Election Test, Loop Prevention Test and other functional tests. I'm quite new to this and can't decide for myself -

is that a correct approach for my purposes or I shouldn't use SDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Yes you can use simpler controller Pox and load spanning tree protocol to test it. 
However, you are only test the management controller ability to avoid such loops etc.  You will need to find a way to load the switch HW capabilities into mininet which I don't know such way.

Comment: It's RSTP not RTSP. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol#Rapid_Spanning_Tree_Protocol) But thank you anyway

Comment: Oh  sorry. My mistake  I conflicted with other streaming protocols. I will update my answer. and Yes you can do it.